# Box Shadow display in joomla helix template

Tags: css, joomla, box-shadow, helix

So I have this problem with box shadow (`box-shadow`) on hover (`:hover`) and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

See the following video:
**http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cb1FoYlcVj**

I need the box shadow of the selected box to go above the other boxes on hover.

If I run the code in the fiddle, it all seems fine: **https://jsfiddle.net/Dreamstardesign/5urrp48f/**

I also tried to edit the CSS of the `"sppb-..."` classes, but nothing seems to work. Anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: I think it might be a z-index problem. Did you try to put space between the blocks and see if the shadow works?

Comment: Z-index doesn't work. And yes when I put gutter between columns the shadow is working.

Comment: Try to change in `.our-services:hover` the `z-index` to 9999

Comment: Try remove white background from .our-service